# Pentaho Data Integration: extract language distribution code

Tags: javascript, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using PDI API to get the language distribution for code in my projects.

Using a request like

```
var url = "http://<my_sonar_instance>/api/measures/component?additionalFields=metrics&component=<sonar_key>&metricKeys=duplicated_lines_density%2Cblocker_violations%2Ccomment_lines_density%2Ccritical_violations%2Cnew_maintainability_rating%2Cnew_duplicated_lines_density%2Cnew_reliability_rating%2Cnew_security_rating%2Cncloc%2Cncloc_language_distribution";
```

and parsing the JSON result by

```
$.component.measures[?(@.metric=="ncloc_language_distribution")].value
```

to assign the value at a variable named

```
sonar_ncloc_language_distribution
```

I obtain for example

```
java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42
```

Now I'd like to assign those values at some variables in a PDI transformation using a Modified JavaScript value using this Javascript code

```
var map = new Map();
sonar_ncloc_language_distribution.split(";").forEach(x => map[x.split("=")[0]] = x.split("=")[1]);

var sonar_ncloc_java = map.java;
var sonar_ncloc_js = map.js;
var sonar_ncloc_jsp = map.jsp;
var sonar_ncloc_web = map.web;
var sonar_ncloc_xml = map.xml;
```

but it doesn't work and the error is

```
Unable compile javascript: 
syntax error (script#2)
```

(NOTE: if I try to execute the javascript code "alone" in a HTML file all works fine ...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var sonar_ncloc_language_distribution = "java=10514;js=237;jsp=3995;web=5;xml=42";

var map = new Map();

sonar_ncloc_language_distribution.split(";").forEach(x => map[x.split("=")[0]] = x.split("=")[1]);
console.log(map);

var sonar_ncloc_java = map.java;
var sonar_ncloc_js = map.js;
var sonar_ncloc_jsp = map.jsp;
var sonar_ncloc_web = map.web;
var sonar_ncloc_xml = map.xml;

console.log(map.java);
console.log(map.js);
console.log(map.jsp);
console.log(map.web);
console.log(map.xml);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: Just a thought. I don't know PDI but I'm guessing there might be some parsing its unable to do. have you tried using an object instead of a new Map? `var map = {};` Then if that doesn't help, next thing I would try is not using the forEach and instead using a for loop.
`snld_array = sonar_ncloc_language_distribution.split(";");for (i=0;i<snld_array.length();i++{const s = x.split("=");map[s[0]] = s[1];}`

Comment: If you decided to use `Map` you should use `get` and `set` like `map.set('key', 2)` and `map.get('key')`. If you assigning by `map[key] = val` you can use simple Array, no Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is result of lacking support for ES6 in Rhino engine.

In browser (or node) you using different javascript engine that have implemented `Map` object documented here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

But you not using this as `Map` should be used - I mean `set` and `get` methods. Instead you using `map` like Array.

So to fix your problem you can simply replace

```
var map = new Map();
```

by

```
var map = [];
```

Sources:

> PDI uses the Rhino engine, from Mozilla. Rhino is an open source implementation of the core JavaScript language; it doesn’t contain objects or methods related to manipulation of web pages.

https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/pentaho-tutorial/transforming-your-data-with-javascript-code-and-the-javascript-step/

Support of `Rhino` for `Map` and `ES6`

https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html

[image]

Comment: I've tried to use `var map = [];` but I still obtain the same error `syntax error` at the line  `sonar_ncloc_language_distribution.split(";").forEach(x => map[x.split("=")[0]] = x.split("=")[1]);`

Comment: Note that arrow functions are also ES6 features so try to replace arrow functions by classical ES5 functions.